# How to use/start the gradle daemon on a Mac?

Tags: gradle, gradle-daemon

Every time I execute a gradle command on Mac I get a message saying:

```
"This build could be faster, please consider using the Gradle Daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html"
```

I've created a gradle.properties file with the line org.gradle.daemon=true as mentioned in the web page given in the message. However no matter what I do, I still continue to get that message.

If I execute the command

```
gradle --daemon
```

then it executes successfully, but still next time I do something I get that message about it could be faster and builds are just as slow as before I started the daemon.

My installation directory is no /Users/username as in gradle_daemon.html as I'm falling a Udacity course (https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud867/) and they recommend installing it to /usr/local/gradle

How can I actually get the gradle dameon to work and get rid of that could be faster message?

(Using Gradle version 2.10)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The page doesn't say anywhere that gradle must be installed in `/Users/username`. It says that this directory is **your** home directory, and that's where the `.gradle/gradle.properties` file must be located. The place where gradle is installed is irrelevant.

Answer (score 29):

just put

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

in the `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` file. Then each build on your machine will use the gradle wrapper and the message dissapears.

Comment: `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` doesn't exists, create it 

      `echo  'org.gradle.daemon=true' > ~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

Comment: Sadly this does not help in the case that the gradle daemon shall run on demand in a project iff there already is a daemon which is usable (so the project must not start something long running at all cost, as this shall be controlled elsewhere).  Running `./gradlew --foreground` forks a daemon, but this one is never used.  So apparently this command is completely useless.